# TypeError: ufunc 'isfinite' not supported for the input types

Tags: python, error-handling, typeerror, analytics, visualization

```
TypeError: ufunc 'isfinite' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

I'm plotting a sports (soccer) heatmap. After struggling to open the csv file with the event data, I changed the encoding to utf-16 and successfully opened the file. Now when I plot the heatmap at the end I get this error. Instead of getting the red pitch as output displaying a player's heatmap, I'm only getting an empty white pitch.

[image: I should get this red type pitch][image: but I only get the white empty pitch]

Comment: You shouild maybe show what you attempted in code first and where the error occured

Comment: I resolved this thanks. I had to change the datatype of the x'y coordinates from string to float.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this thank you. I had to change the datatype of the x'y coordinates from string to float.